# Experience with wavemaker and amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, wavemaker

I am new to [wavemaker](http://www.wavemaker.com) but the development with it seems to be straightforward.

I tried to invoke some calls to the amazon Product Advertising API (with SOAP) but it didn't work. The problem seems to be that every call has to be signed (see e.g. here: http://www.mularien.com/blog/2009/08/13/tutorial-amazon-soap-product-advertising...)

This seems to render the whole endeavor really burdensome. Has anyone done this and successfully included this API into a wavemaker application? (examples with REST are of course also welcome).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signing requirement does really complicate the whole thing.

Instead of importing the WSDL into WaveMaker and using the WaveMaker generated client, you can use the mularien example code as a java service.

Generate the client following the example and add the jars and classes to your project classpath.
Add a java service to your WaveMaker project.
In the java service, any/all public methods are exposed to the browser client. 
So if you com.mularien.amazon.AmazonProductSearch is your java service class, getAmazonInfo(String) would be callable by the client.

Alternatively, instead of directly exposing the AmazonProductSearch functions, use your java service class as a manager. For example, you might want to return only a sub set of Item_type3. A wrapper/manager class as a your project service between the client and AmazonProductSearch can provide that.

Comment: I try to use wavemaker because I don't have the skills to do the hardcore java programming myself - nor have I the time... All of this seems to go into the direction of just that, so I guess, I just leave it at that if there is no other, easier method. Do you work with wavemaker yourself? Perhaps you could add some screenshots how to accomplish the steps you describe in your answer? (Perhaps it is easier than it sounds at first?!?) That would be great! Thank you in any case!